# Creating new model in sqlalchemy triggers INSERT on database

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

While writing new test I found quite curious case:

```
models.ArticleTag(tag=tag, article=article)
```

Triggers INSERT statement on database even though there is no Session.add after.

However if I change code to look like this:

```
models.ArticleTag(tag.id=tag.id, article=article)
```

No INSERT will ever happen.

Article in this case is fresh object that is not in db yet and tag is something that we have already in db.

My models look like this:

```
class Tag(object):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'

    title = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Unicode(255), nullable=False)
    type = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Unicode(255))
    uid = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Unicode(32), primary_key=True, nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (
        sqlalchemy.UniqueConstraint('type', 'title', name='title_type_unique'),
    )


class ArticleTag(object):
    """Represent m2m table between Tags and Article.
    association obj for mapping m2m articles<->tags
    """
    __tablename__ = 'article_tag'

    article_uid = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Unicode(32), sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('article.uid'), primary_key=True)
    tag_uid = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Unicode(32), sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('tag.uid'), primary_key=True)

    priority = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, default=0)

    tag = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('Tag', backref='articles')


class Article(object):
    __tablename__ = 'article'

    uid = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Unicode(32), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Unicode(255), nullable=False)
    meta_description = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Unicode(255))
    meta_title = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Unicode(255))
    body = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Unicode)
    is_active = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Boolean, default=True)

    # any tags we have
    article_tags = sqlalchemy.orm.relationship('ArticleTag', backref='article', cascade='all, delete-orphan', order_by=lambda: sqlalchemy.desc(ArticleTag.priority))

    @property
    def tags(self):
        """Helper method that will return tags sorted by priority.
        """
        return [art_tag.tag for art_tag in self.article_tags]
```

My guess is that I do not know something quite important about sqlalchemy.

Anyone can point me a direction?

Comment: Enable SQL statement logging (via `create_engine(..., echo=True)` or using logging module) and you can see all SQL statement generated and executed by sqlalchemy. It will give you the clue about what sqlalchemy is doing differently.

Comment: I am going to guess that you have `autocommit` set to `True` in your configs. Try setting that to `False`.

Comment: @adarsh I have autocommit set, however my question is why sqlalchemy triggers database insert on merely spawning new instance of the orm model.

Comment: @van no idea how it supposed to help me really ;-D

Comment: Not completely sure about this, but since you have autocommit set to true, sqlalchemy will consider each instantiation as a transaction and it will commit to database. Your second example shouldn't work because its not valid python syntax